# Convert SVG to AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, file-format

I have an SVG file that I would like to convert to an AI file.  Can I just open the SVG in Adobe Illustrator and then save it as an AI file?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly yes. But the two formats are not 100% mutually compatible so there are corner cases where this does in fact not work, but those features are rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of RGB and CMYK - SVG is mostly in RGB without a ICC-Profile.
I refer to this one:
[SVG with ICC Profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405689/svg-image-with-cmyk-colours-is-it-possible)
You possibly want to convert from RGB to CMYK. This depends on your Colorsettings in Illustrator (ICC-Profile)